# Seekbar OnSeekBarChangeListener not called for changes with DPAD left and right?

Tags: android, seekbar

I have SeekBar widget, trying to control it by dpad keys - change position by left and right.

I can focus it, pressing dpad left/right changes position (correctly, as set by 
`setKeyProgressIncrement`), however, there's no way from my code to know that such change occured. `OnSeekBarChangeListener` is not called in this case.

Looking at `AbsSeekBar.java`, I see code in `onKeyDown` which moves progress by keys, however it doesn't call any callback. It only calls its internal onKeyChange, which can't be trapped.

Anyone has way to detect seekbar movement by cursor keys?

I want make my app nice also on non-touch-screen devices.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?